# Two conditions in a for loop

Tags: php

Why does this for loop work with each condition on their own, but together the first condition doesn't matter?

```
for ($j = 0; $j < 5 or $j < $synCount; $j++)
```

I only want the loop run five times

or

if synCount is less than this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably mean "`$j` under 5 ***and*** `$j` under `$sysCount`", or:

```
$j < min(5, $sysCount)
```

Comment: Didn't know about this functionality. More elegant than my solution, nice one!

Answer (score 2):

very simple

```
$j < min(5, $sysCount)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can youse the `break` statement to leave the for loop :

```
for ($j = 0; $j < 5 ; $j++)
{
   if( $j >= $synCount )
      break;
   //treatment
}
```

Or calculate your limit before the loop :

```
$ max = $synCount < 5 ? $synCount : 5;
for ($j = 0; $j < $synCount  ; $j++)
{
   //treatment
}
```

Another solution,quickest : use `min()` :

```
for ($j = 0; $j < min(5, $synCount)  ; $j++)
{
   //treatment
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$loopcount = ($syncount < 5) ? $syncount : 5;
for ($j = 0; $j < $loopcount; ++$j) {
}
```

The first line determines whether `$syncount` is less than 5 or not and then assigns a value to `$loopcount` based on that.  Then the loop runs the required number of times.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($j = 0; $j < ($syncCount <= 5 ? $syncCount : 5); $j++)
```

or slightly optimized (but I guess with 5 or less iterations this *absolutely* doesn't matter)

```
for ($j = 0, $limit = min($syncCount, 5); $j < $limit; $j++)
```

Anothe nice solutions

```
foreach (range(0, min($syncCount, 5)) as $j)
```

---

Sidenote

```
$syncCount <= 5 ? $syncCount : 5  ==  min($syncCount, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$productsprice=ProductPrice::model()->findAllByAttributes(array ('product_id'=>$products_data->product_id));
foreach($productsprice AS $productsprice):
   for($quantity = 0; $quantity <= 10; $quantity++)
   {
      echo '<li >'.array(value=>'ProductPrice::model()->getquantity($data->quantity)').'</li>' ;
   }
 endforeach;
```

Comment: Please add some details about your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two conditions may indeed be applied inside `for` loop using logical operator. For example check status until it's *ok*

```
for($i = 0; $i < 100 && $status != 'ok'; $i++){
    sleep(1);
    $status = checkStatus();
}
```

Otherwise you need to use additional *if* expression with *break*

```
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++){
    sleep(1);
    $status = checkStatus();
    if($status == 'ok') break;
}
```